# JAVA application with file write/output on linux cant be read by non root user

Tags: java, linux, web-services, file, tomcat

We have this JAVA webservice that runs on tomcat 9(installed by root).

The webservice creates a generic file log for our client. The problem is only the root user can read and access the file that is being generated.

My question is can I change the output file to be readable for all users by default? (without using chmod everytime the file is generated)

Should it be on code level or configure it on linux?

I have read about this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html.

But one of our old redhat servers dont have a code level config on its webservice and its working fine.

Thanks

Comment: The Oracle link you post has a link to a "Managing Metadata" web page.  Did you read that?

Comment: Yes, the problem is im thinking if I should do it on code level or not. The answer from @GhostCat might be the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be looking at this from a "java io" side of things. 
This is a **user permission** problem. In other words: probably your tomcat servers shouldn't be running as **root** in the very first place.

Consider creating a special **user** that is used to run your tomcat instance. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371809/run-tomcat7-as-tomcat7-or-any-other-user) you can find guidance how you could do that for an Ubuntu system. And your favorite search engine will for sure know similar links for your favorite Linux distribution, too.

That might also be better from a **security** perspective: do you really want that people attacking your tomcat ... end up being **root** on your system if they succeed?!

Long story short: your problem is not some java code within tomcat that writes files; and then other users on your system being unable to access those files. Your problem is that your tomcat service is running as root! Fix the later; and your "initial" problem will be fixed, too.

Final word of **warning** though: I am not saying that it is **easy** to change the user setup for you. Maybe it is; but especially if your setup is using "root" for a long time, then there is a certain chance that other things you put in place rely on "being root". So, "not being root" is the right direction; but it might be a painful path to get there, from where you are now.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will read it now. Will update the answer once I resolve my issue.

Comment: Fyi: just updated my answer with some words of warning. I hope you don't need them; but on the other hand; I want to avoid that you get the impression that changing your setup might be a "simple" thing to do.

Comment: Yes that is my problem now. It seems like its kinda tricky to just change into tomcat user especially when the application is already on production stage. Thanks